# DateTime convert from varchar

Tags: sql, datetime-format

I'm looking for some help. I have a date field as **2015/08/08T12:00GMT** for a school project. I have only had one class on sql, so Im really new to this. My situation is this:

I need the `varchar(50)` **2015/08/08T12:00GMT** converted to a date type. I dont know how to do this in sql. I have tired cast, and convert, and I keep getting errors, and failures on conversion.

I have been searching, and trying different methods, just not getting results. Any help would be so appreicated, thank you!

Comment: `select convert(datetime, replace(replace('2015/08/08T12:00GMT', '/', '-'), 'GMT', '') + ':00', 127)` Might not be the best way. Also I'm assuming you're only using GMT.

Comment: I have three different files that I have to merge. This particular file Im working with now is GMT only. Next is UTC. and last is                         2015-08-07T15:00:00Z Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Michael, in the future it would be good for you to included all the variations in your question.

Comment: Thank you. I will make sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an idea to get you thinking about possible approaches and solutions:

```
declare @T varchar(100) = '2015/08/08T12:00GMT';
select
    convert(
        datetime,
        replace(
            case when right(@T, 3) in ('GMT', 'UTC')
                then left(@T, len(@T) - 3) + ':00Z'
                else @T
            end,
            '/', '-'
        ),
        127
    );
```

The documentation spells out the formats recognized by the function [`convert()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx%20Convert).